# Why would an Excel 2010 spreadsheet with VBA lag when opened with other large excel spreadsheets already opened

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've got a relatively small (~100K) Excel 2010 spreadsheet that (via VBA) when opened, closes all worksheets except the start page, checks the user name and cross checks it with a SQL table, bringing back the user's record to check their permissions.

A few cells are updated rangeUserName, rangeCurrentUser, rangeSystemAccess etc...

If I open this workbook when there are other large spreadsheets (that also have vba), it takes about 30 to 60 seconds to open, when if no other workbooks are open, it takes under 5 seconds.

Why is this?

Comment: Does this happen again if you (re-)save the file after you opened it ?

I had a similar issue once and got it solved by reading: http://excel2007-slow-open-file.blogspot.nl/

Comment: Yes it does happen if I resave it after I open it and I don't think it relates to that.

Comment: Do you know where in the VBA it stalls?

Comment: This should not have been migrated from stack overflow given it is VBA related

Comment: Check the on open macro to see what it is doing, it seems this is the problem?

Comment: I can't see that the open code is an issue as it is fine if there are no other workbooks open.

Comment: closes all worksheets -> here could be the error, depending on how you loop to achieve this. also there might be events related bugs, which cause your lag - this is highly depending on your VBA-codes. have you tried this while decativating vba in the large file? if it is better then, you should post your code of the smaller file.

Comment: Are you forcing a recalculate on all open workbooks by setting
calculation to manual at the start and then back to automatic at the end of your routine?

Answer (score 1):

By default Excel opens each file within a single EXCEL.EXE process - you can watch this in the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager.

So continuing to open files can cause contention within that process - eventually it will run out of memory and slow down or crash.

To avoid this, you can start subsequent Excel windows as a separate EXCEL.EXE process.  You do this by holding down the Shift key while you choose Excel from the Start menu or click it in your Taskbar.  Once they launched as separate processes, Windows seems to manage the resources better - I believe it swaps inactive processes out to Virtual Memory.

For Excel 2013 they have made that game a bit harder - you have to hold down Shift + Alt until a confirmation window appears.

I tend to open every Excel window this way, especially if working with large files, VBA code, Pivot Tables, External Data or Add-Ins.  As well as avoiding resource issues in the first place, it means that you only lose your work in one window if there is a crash or freeze, rather than losing all of them at once.